# basic python misunderstanding of dict (TypeError: string indices must be integers)

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm beginning to learn python and I try to make a turing machine app, using pyQt. I get from a`QTextEdit` some "code" and put it in a `dict` and get something like :

`{'1': {'a': ['s', 'D', '2'], 's': ['s', 'G', '2']}, '2': {'a': ['a', 'D', '1']}}`

I have this function  where `table` is a Dict:

```
def execute_TM(self, table, ruban, etat1):
    self.Ruban.position = 1
    self.table = table
    etatAct = etat1
    while etatAct != 'stop':
        symb = self.Ruban.lire_cellules()
        # print symb
        print self.table
        nvSymb = self.table[etatAct][symb][0]
        self.Ruban.ecrire(nvSymb)
        if table[etatAct][symb][1] == 'D':
            self.Ruban.deplacement_droite()
        if table[etatAct][symb][1] == 'G':
            self.Ruban.deplacement_gauche()
        else:
            print
            "erreur code deplacement"
        etatAct = table[etatAct][symb][2]
```

And I get this error :

```
nvSymb = self.table[etatAct][symb][0]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I have been reading lot of post about this error, and tried different things...But I still don't understand.

**Edit :** 
Thanks to your help, I'm trying to understand, so if I have :

`table={'1': {'a': ['s', 'D', '2'], 's': ['s', 'G', '2']}, '2': {'a': ['a', 'D', '1']}}`

And then I want to get from the main key `'1'` and from the key `'s'` the second element of the list : `'G'`
I can call `table['1']['s'][1]` so it something like:

`table["here it's a string"]["here it's also a string"]["here it's an integer"]`

and it work :

```
>>> table={'1': {'a': ['s', 'D', '2'], 's': ['s', 'G', '2']}, '2': {'a':['a', 'D', '1']}}
>>> etatAct='1'
>>> symb='s'
>>> table[etatAct][symb][1]
'G'
```

I still don't understand why it do not work in the function....

**Edit2 :**

Using `type()` I have found that `self.table` is not a `dict` but a `PyQt4.QtCore.QStringList`anyone know how to easily transform it ?

Comment: Show the code where you get the value for `table`. It appears to be a string, not a dict.

Comment: @DavidG `print self.table` is not the same as `print` and `self.table` on different lines, please be more careful when editing (and that some of your reviewers approved this is ...)

Answer (score 3):

You will understand what is the error from this,

```
In [10]: a = 'Hellooo'
In [11]: print a[0]
H
In [12]: print a['0']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-175cb7ceb755> in <module>()
----> 1 print a['0']

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

> In your code trying to index string with string instead of dictionary.

Comment: thanks I understand this for a `list` but in my case I would like to call from : `table={'1': {'a': ['s', 'D', '2'], 's': ['s', 'G', '2']}, '2': {'a': ['a', 'D', '1']}}` something like `table['1']['s'][1]` and get `'G'` how should I do that ?

Comment: Accessing elements in `dict` and `list` are different. Here you showed an example having `list` in `dict` so it have to call like that only.

Answer (score 1):

From your error its clear that one of the indexes of (etatAct, symb) is not an integer but string.

```
nvSymb=self.table[etatAct][symb][0]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

You can try it by converting it to integers.

```
 nvSymb=self.table[int(etatAct)][int(symb)][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take this:

```
nvSymb=self.table[etatAct][symb][0]
```

apart so you can see where you get a string:

```
tmp = self.table[etatAct]
nvSymb = tmp[symb][0]
```

and see whether `self.table` or `self.table[etaAct]` is a string that gets indexed by a non-integer. Starting with that knowledge that you shoud be able to solve this correcting your input.